# How to mock cursor.execute

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am trying to write a test for the below code without integrating a mysql database. Is it possible?

```
def sql_query_select(select, table, condition, variable):
    cursor = database_connection("cursor")
    sql_query = "SELECT " + select + " from " + table + " where " + condition + " = " + "'" + variable + "'"
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    try:
        response = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    except:
        response = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    return response
```

I have tried the following code as a test

```
@mock.patch("lambda_function.database_connection")
    @mock.patch("pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute")
    def test_sql_query_select(self, mock_database_connection, mock_execute):
        mock_database_connection.return_value = "cursor"
        mock_execute.return_value = "test"
        self.assertEqual(lambda_function.sql_query_select("select", "table", "condition", "variable"), "execute")
```

But get the following error and am not sure how to proceed.

```
E       AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Comment: Just one thing I noticed about this code is it seems like you are testing on almost entirely mocks (cursor, db and connection). Although it might not be ideal, even testing on something like an SQLITE file in this instance may be better to ensure you get more realistic testing, or if your code is mysql specific then running tests in CI/CD might be better.

Comment: Pro tip: don't build SQL queries by concatenating strings. This is a security flaw that allows sql injection attacks. Instead, you should use bound parameters in your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already trying to mock `database_connection()`. You don't need to also mock `cursor.execute()` since you can inject the behavior you want to the return value of `database_connection()`. The problem is that you need to mock objects **where they are used** rather than where they are defined. It looks like `sql_query_select()` is in a file named `lambda_function.py`, so the mock looks like this:

```
@mock.patch(lambda_function.database_connection)
def test_sql_query_select(self, mock_database_connection):
    mock_record = ('record one', 'record two')
    mock_database_connection.return_value.fetchone.return_value = mock_record
    result = lambda_function.sql_query_select("select", "table", "condition", "variable")
    self.assert_equal(mock_record, result)
```

One problem with this kind of test is that it completely ignores the parameters to `sql_query_select()`. One solution is to verify that `database_connection.return_value.execute` was called.

This is also unsatisfying since you are testing implementation rather than behavior.